# Why does my list does not work

Tags: r

I have a function which check for me my list. I have a list with two vectors. instead of repeating my code, I tried to use `for` loop. However, the for loop does not work as expected.

Here is my code:

```
 x <- c(2,3,4,5)
 y <- c(2,4,6,7)
 z <- list(x,y)
 pscale <- numeric()
 pscale <- list()
 for(i in 1:4){#length of my vector
 for(j in 1:2){#length of z
 pscale[[j]][[i]] <- ifelse(z[[j]][[i]] %in% c(2,9,10),0.01,1)
 }
 }
Error in `*tmp*`[[j]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work.

```
x <- c(2,3,4,5)
y <- c(2,4,6,7)
z <- list(x,y)
pscale <- list()
length(pscale) <- 2 # set length to the number of vectors
for(i in 1:4){#length of my vector
  for(j in 1:2){#length of z
    pscale[[j]][i] <- ifelse(z[[j]][i] %in% c(2,9,10),0.01,1)
  }
}
```

Comment: I have many vectors and need the function works automatically

Comment: I edited my answer. If you know number of your vectors then set length of list.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to declare `pscale` as matrix:

```
x <- c(2,3,4,5)
y <- c(2,4,6,7)
z <- list(x,y)
pscale <- matrix(rep(NA,length(x)*length(z)), length(z), length(x))
for(i in 1:4) {
 for(j in 1:2) {
   pscale[j,i] <- ifelse(z[[j]][[i]] %in% c(2,9,10), 0.01, 1)
 }
}
pscale

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,] 0.01    1    1    1
# [2,] 0.01    1    1    1
```

Otherwise, defining `pscale` as a list:

```
x <- c(2,3,4,5)
y <- c(2,4,6,7)
z <- list(x,y)
pscale <- vector(length(z), mode="list")
for(i in 1:4) {
 for(j in 1:2) {
  pscale[[j]][[i]] <- ifelse(z[[j]][[i]] %in% c(2,9,10), 0.01, 1)
 }
}
pscale

# [[1]]
# [1] 0.01 1.00 1.00 1.00
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 0.01 1.00 1.00 1.00
```

Comment: could you please explain what does `2` means in `vector(2, ..)`. Is it the number of my vectors?

Comment: @Alice Yes, `2` is the number of vectors: `x` and `y`. You can use `vector(length(z),mode="list")`.